# How to create media player in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create media player in vb.net. It will supports all the different file formats like wmv,flv,mpg etc.,

Anybody know this please help me

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose? Is it for learning or for commercial purpose?

If you are making it just for home project, I will discourage you from doing such thing. If it is for learning, then it has to be some Harvard/Oxford/MIT research project not just some fun project. Why I am telling all this? Because supporting even a single format by your code is a big thing. Forget about supporting all the different formats. Before supporting all formats you need to understand different codecs. There are codecs to support different formats.

None of the major medial players (Windows media player, real etc.) support every format. They again depend on installation of codecs to support different formats. VLC player seems to be playing every format because it bundles most of the codecs within itself.

One thing you can do is place VLC player ActiveX control in your VB.Net form and use its functionality.

And if you are doing it for commercial purpose, then anyway vb.net is a wrong language to do so.

HTH.